# call the appropriate function with arguments based on key received

Tags: c++

In my application I'm calling different functions based on the message key received via network. But my implementation isn't that effective as it consists of exhaustive search for the key in the `std::vector<std::string>`. I'm thinking of using `std::unordered_map<std::string, <fun>>` but don't know how to map it to a function and also call that function by passing the required arguments. This is my current implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> msg_key_list;
    msg_key_list.emplace_back("key1");
    msg_key_list.emplace_back("key2");
    msg_key_list.emplace_back("key3");
    msg_key_list.emplace_back("key4");
    msg_key_list.emplace_back("key5");

    char buff[2048];
    ssize_t data_len;
    while (true) {
        // receive data from network

        std::string msg(buff, data_len);
        std::string::size_type pos = msg.find_first_of(",");
        std::string key = msg.substr(0, pos - 1);
        if (key == msg_key_list.at(0)) {
            // validate the message received
            bool valid;
            if (!valid) {
                std::cerr << "Invalid data: ";
                std::cerr << __FILE__ << ", " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ", " << __LINE__ << "\n";

                continue;
            }

            std::string val(buff + pos, msg.size() - pos);
            // fun1(val);
        } else if (key == msg_key_list.at(1)) {
            // validate the message received
            bool valid;
            if (!valid) {
                std::cerr << "Invalid data: ";
                std::cerr << __FILE__ << ", " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ", " << __LINE__ << "\n";

                continue;
            }

            std::string val(buff + pos, msg.size() - pos);
            // fun2(val);
        } else if (key == msg_key_list.at(2)) {
            // validate the message received
            bool valid;
            if (!valid) {
                std::cerr << "Invalid data: ";
                std::cerr << __FILE__ << ", " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ", " << __LINE__ << "\n";

                continue;
            }

            std::string val(buff + pos, msg.size() - pos);
            // fun3(val);
        } else if (key == msg_key_list.at(3)) {
            // validate the message received
            bool valid;
            if (!valid) {
                std::cerr << "Invalid data: ";
                std::cerr << __FILE__ << ", " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ", " << __LINE__ << "\n";

                continue;
            }

            std::string val(buff + pos, msg.size() - pos);
            // fun4(val);
        } else if (key == msg_key_list.at(4)) {
            // validate the message received
            bool valid;
            if (!valid) {
                std::cerr << "Invalid data: ";
                std::cerr << __FILE__ << ", " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ", " << __LINE__ << "\n";

                continue;
            }

            std::string val(buff + pos, msg.size() - pos);
            // fun5(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have used queues consumers... So depending on the key, you produce a message for a specific queue, then consumers look for messages in their assigned queues...

Comment: <O/T> `bool valid; if(!valid)...` is undefined behavior, `valid` is never initialized

Comment: @PhoenixBlue do you mean publisher/subscriber kind of?

Comment: @Harry exactly!

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>>`?

Comment: @yano I know I need to assign it by writing a validator function that returns a bool. As of  now I'm just telling what my code does.

Comment: you could have a `std::map` (why `unordered`?) of `key --> functionPtr`

Comment: or `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<SomeInterface>>`, you need to use classes though

Comment: @appleapple do you think its possible to map functions that take different types of arguments as well?

Comment: speculating here of course, but what's so different about `fun1` - `fun5`? They're all accepting a string `val` that's constructed exactly the same way no matter the key is. Could those functions be consolidated?

Comment: @yano The reason I asked is may be I need to call a function that takes different types of arguments depending on the key.

Comment: oh ok. Strongly recommend cleaning up/clarifying your code and question. You've got dozens of lines dedicated to irrelevant validation code that's UB anyway, and the part you do care about (the function calls) are comments that aren't illustrative of what you actually want to do (passing different numbers/types of arguments). I didn't learn these function calls might take different arguments until 9 comments deep.

Comment: In terms of an answer, function overloading is the first thought that comes to my mind, but there's not enough info to know if that could work. You also might be able to construct a `fun` with an appropriate set of default arguments. Not sure if there's a way to create a map with different value types, `boost` might have something that does that. Lookup table probably your simplest implementation, although inelegant. Even with a lookup table, I'd still replace the `vector` with a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: @Harry you can type-erase the data to one signature, maybe `std::any`, either done at callback directly or you wrap them when register. and use `std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::any)>>`

Comment: @Harry or `SomeInterface` have multiple entry point.

Comment: @Harry it's hard to say without more detail. Any you may drop some benefit of static type check by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example of how I whould approach this (if all handlers would share the same function signature). I also avoid the string copying in the message handler because that would slow things done unecessarily.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// function signature of your message handlers
using handler_t = void(*)(const std::string_view&);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// handler functions

void handler_1(const std::string_view& msg)
{
    // validate data here
    std::cout << "handler 1 : " << msg << std::endl;
};

void handler_2(const std::string_view& msg)
{
    std::cout << "handler 2 : " << msg << std::endl;
};


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// handler selection 

void handle_message(const std::string& buffer)
{
    static const std::map<std::string_view, handler_t> handler_map
    {
        {"key1",handler_1},
        {"key2",handler_2}
    };

    try
    {
        // find location of first ',' (if any)
        // also ensure the ',' is not too far back for splitting
        auto index = buffer.find_first_of(',');

        if ((index != std::string::npos) && (index < (buffer.length() - 1)))
        {
            auto pos = buffer.begin() + index;

            // No need to copy data to seperate strings
            // string_views will do.
            std::string_view key{ buffer.begin(), pos };
            std::string_view data{ pos + 1, buffer.end() };

            // lookup handler, not if no handler is found
            // a std::out_of_range exception will be thrown
            auto handler = handler_map.at(key);

            // call the handler
            handler(data);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range&)
    {
        // todo decide what you want to do with incorrect messages here
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// and handle a test message in main

int main()
{
    const std::string data{ "key1,Hello" };
    handle_message(data);
}
```